# POST data not seen in stores after 1.7 -> 1.9 upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, php, apache, post-data

I recently upgraded our Magento from **v1.7** to **v1.9.3.2**, and now I'm noticing something strange - none of the POST requests seem to be working on the stores, but they *do* work on the Magento admin backend.

A good example would be when I try to login to one of the stores, I'll fill the form out and click submit, and I can see via the Networking tab that the POST request does get sent, and I can see in the Apache logs that the request came in, but when the action page loads, it loads as if no POST data was sent/received. For example, when I try to login, I would expect it to either log me in, or show an error (EG: wrong password), but it just re-loads the form, with no alerts/errors. This is the same behavior for the registration form and password reset form.

Here's the Apache access log activity when I attempt to login to a store as a customer:

```
==> /var/log/httpd/magento_ssl_access.log <==
12.34.56.78 - - [10/May/2017:16:22:44 -0700] "POST /index.php/customer/account/loginPost/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly90ZXN0LmxpYmVydHlkaXN0cmlidXRpb24uY29tL2luZGV4LnBocC9jdXN0b21lci9hY2NvdW50L2luZGV4Lw,,/ HTTP/1.1" 302 20
12.34.56.78 - - [10/May/2017:16:22:45 -0700] "GET /index.php/customer/account/ HTTP/1.1" 302 20
12.34.56.78 - - [10/May/2017:16:22:45 -0700] "GET /index.php/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly90ZXN0LmxpYmVydHlkaXN0cmlidXRpb24uY29tL2luZGV4LnBocC9jdXN0b21lci9hY2NvdW50L2luZGV4Lw,,/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3449
12.34.56.78 - - [10/May/2017:16:22:46 -0700] "GET /media//partner.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2638
```

> **Note**: I tailed `/var/www/html/magento-app/base/var/log*` and `/var/log/httpd/*`, but the only log file that had any activity was `magento_ssl_access.log`

#### Specs

- Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
- PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2017 08:09:42)
- Zend Engine v2.6.0
- Magento Version: 1.9.3.2

I'm not too sure where to go from here. I would think that if its something to do with Apache or PHP, then I would be able to replicate it on the admin backend, but thats not the case.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!